# Make a ndarray based on index stored in nparray

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array [0,1,1,2,0,2]. I wish to make a ndarray:

```
array([[[1],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [1],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [1],
        [1],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [1],
        [0],
        [1]]])
```

Is there a way to do with just numpy functions without using any loops or list comprehension? Thanks.

Currently, what I did was

```
a = np.array([0,1,1,2,0,2])
len_a = len(a)
unique_count_a = len(np.unique(a))
t = np.ndarray(shape = (unique_count_a,len_a,1),dtype = int,buffer = np.zeros(len_a * unique_count_a))


for i in range(unique_count_a):
    for j in range(len_a):
        if i == j:
            t[i,j]=1
```

Comment: What's your logic?  Show your attempt, even it uses loops or list comprehension.  We expect some effort, even it doesn't get you all the way.  Plus its easier to compare our answers against a working example.

Comment: How does the input relate to the output? Is it some sort of one-hot encoding?

Comment: Very vaguely asked. Could you elaborate or improve on your question?

Comment: Edited. Sorry I did not asked it clearly

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = [0,1,1,2,0,2]

out = np.zeros((max(a)+1, len(a), 1), dtype=int)
out[a, np.r_[:len(a)]] = 1
print(out)
```

It gives:

```
[[[1]
  [0]
  [0]
  [0]
  [1]
  [0]]

 [[0]
  [1]
  [1]
  [0]
  [0]
  [0]]

 [[0]
  [0]
  [0]
  [1]
  [0]
  [1]]]
```

Comment: `out.reshape((-1, 6, 1))`

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about reshaping....

Answer (score 0):

We don't normally use `ndarray`, unless constructing an special array from a preexisting buffer.  All you need is:

```
t1 = np.zeros((unique_count_a,len_a,1),dtype = int)
```

Since that last size 1 dimension makes the display longer, I'll omit that

```
In [450]: t[:,:,0]
Out[450]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

That's not what you display.

But we can easily generate it with:

```
In [451]: (np.arange(unique_count_a)[:,None]==np.arange(len_a))
Out[451]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False]])
In [452]: (np.arange(unique_count_a)[:,None]==np.arange(len_a)).astype(int)
Out[452]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

What I think you want is:

```
In [454]: u = np.unique(a)
In [457]: for i in range(t1.shape[0]):
     ...:     for j in range(t1.shape[1]):
     ...:         if u[i]==a[j]:
     ...:             t1[i,j] = 1
     ...: 
In [458]: t1
Out[458]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Let's just compare the unique values against `a`:

```
In [460]: u[:,None]==a
Out[460]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True]])
In [461]: (u[:,None]==a).astype(int)
Out[461]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

We could easily reshape it to (3,6,1).